# How many Sub-Groups are there for G?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, real-numbers, natural-numbers

Let $G=\Bbb Z_{1980}$ and 2 sub-groups $H_1=\langle85\rangle, H_2=\langle117\rangle$

I found that 45 generates $H_1 \cap H_2$  and that number of element in the latter is 45 too.

Plus I know that there are 24 generators is $H_1 \cap H_2$.

How can I find number of all sub groups of $H_1 \cap H_2$?

I found 2, $H_1 \cap H_2$ itself and ${e}$.

Note: I don't need to find them just know their number.

Comment: What do $H_1$ and $H_2$ have to do with counting the number of subgroups of $G$? As to counting them: subgroups of cyclic groups are cyclic and there is a well-known correspondence between the subgroups and number-theoretic properties of the order. You just need to apply it here.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin what is it?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin so is it 6?

Comment: You want me to spoonfeed you the answers. I want you to figure them out yourself using that theorem. Your approach right now runs afoul of the standards of this site; your post is confused and confusing, with no context.